# Function signature for overloads matching order in TypeScript when passing any or Record

Tags: typescript

I'm running into an issue with `Record<string, unknown>` (and naturally also `Record<string, any>`) matching a type I didn't expect to.

The following code exemplifies the situation:

```js
interface ObjWithProp {
    prop?: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}
interface ObjWithPropFalsy extends ObjWithProp {
    prop?: false;
}
interface ObjWithPropTruthy extends ObjWithProp {
    prop: true;
}

const a: Record<string, unknown> = { prop: true };
const b: ObjWithPropFalsy = a;

if (b.prop) { // b.prop is of type false | undefined
    console.log("typing says it never happens")
} else {
    console.log("typing says it always happens")
}
```

Running the code above prints `typing says it never happens`.

Why does Typescript allow the assignment of `Record<string, unknown>` into the type `ObjWithPropFalsy` if I can't assign `unknown` into `false | undefined`?

I ran into this issue because I'm offering multiple function signatures:

```js
function f(arg: ObjWithPropTruthy): number;
function f(arg: ObjWithPropFalsy): string;
function f(arg: ObjWithProp): number | string;
function f(arg: ObjWithProp): number | string {
    if (arg.prop) return 0;
    else return "0"
}
```

But calling the function with a loosely typed object matches the first signature instead of the last one:

```js
const c: Record<string, unknown> = { prop: true }; // hapens with any as well
const d = f(a);
//    ^ type is 'string' instead of 'number | string' (or hopefully 'number')
```

How can I achieve the intended return type inference in the overload example above?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the mix of what happens in javascript and typescript. The property is evaluated in javscript and there is nothing preventing you in typescript from both ObjWithPropTruthy and ObjWithPropFalsy both running into the if statement. If you look at the output js you can see all of the type information falls away.

```
"use strict";
const a = { prop: true };
const b = a;
if (b.prop) {
    console.log("typing says it never happens");
}
else {
    console.log("typing says it always happens");
}
function f(arg) {
    if (arg.prop)
        return 0;
    else
        return "0";
}

const c = { prop: true }; // hapens with any as well
```

Because you are explicitly casting `a` the assignment with `prop: true` does not narrow the type and allows you to set b with it because you've explicitly set it up to do so. You've basically made prop:true forgotten by typescript because you have defined it as a looser type. In your case you are looking for type guards

```
interface ObjWithProp {
    prop?: boolean;
    [key: string]: any;
}

interface ObjWithPropFalsy extends ObjWithProp {
    prop?: false;
}
interface ObjWithPropTruthy extends ObjWithProp {
    prop?: true;
}

function TruthyCheck(obj:any ):obj is ObjWithPropTruthy{
  return obj && obj.prop === true;
}

function FalsyCheck(obj:any ):obj is ObjWithPropTruthy{
  return obj && obj.prop === false;
}

const a: Record<string, unknown> = { prop: true };
const b: ObjWithPropFalsy = a;



function f(arg: ObjWithPropTruthy): number;
function f(arg: ObjWithPropFalsy): string;
function f(arg: ObjWithProp): number | string | undefined {
    if (TruthyCheck(arg)) return 0;
    else if (FalsyCheck(arg))  return "0"
    return undefined;
}



const c: Record<string, unknown> = { prop: true }; // hapens with any as well
console.log(f(b))
console.log(f(c))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWB1YYAWAClAPYAOyA3gFDJ3JmlkD8AXMuiSQDYRwgBuWvQDaAawgBPdgGcwUUAHMAuu36ShAX2rVQkWIhQYceIkwBicbjMnIIAD0ggAJjLRZcBYuSrC6jcjZkeGsILV1waHgkdxMvJgAVKABXAlsHJ1dYzzMfGnoGJiD5ZLDqbWoYZJAEMGASEGQk1PxJAGF8CAQxAAoSLFZ1ZABKVn7MZGA3YxzvMma0-OQoCDBkqEbx5AAybeRxgDoAigBeM+QSsoqqmrqG5Etrds7uvoGh0a2p7NM5hdalis1ht9lgdntDsdkGcTsErDIrjoEA05Mg4OwAEpdEhQZwAHjkChAigANMhqmIQCQAO4gAB80KohXI7EuyE0QmRIFR6HYM1+FnhtlhcCEOkq1Vq9UaMB6cCgij5HgF5H+klGyBAyQAtuhoEIblL7rL5YqfvFyI8bBrCUoDZK7jK5QqlXFcmQNVrddBkAAfZC24n227S4LOs38i0e9hevVQP0B+RKBPVZwQGCgCDOXwFYAwZA9NUdLq9U3DYbLVbrRoABiEBQgoUm+Z6VueJfD5boQOryAARDW+35K8DGqn05nnOFxVzUQhMdjcQSk8SyRSqbSGbDKMyyKyUigOcgAPTH5D4OBkCDc5DU0xokC2OBuamN7jUWc8CAHbgkRQ9WV0HLD8US-H8-wAnoEHLIA)

I removed an unnecessary overload definition. I also added undefined as a return type, you don't need to.

Comment: I understand why the execution enters the first if. What I don't understand is why Typescript allows me to assign (without explicit cast) `Record<string, unknown>` as `ObjWithPropFalsy` if I can't assign `unknown` to `false | undefined`. Sorry, I'm going to clarify the question.

Comment: In the example, if `ObjWithPropTruthy` has `prop: true` instead of `prop?: true`, then `f(c)` returns `string` instead of `number`.

Comment: unknown isn't assignable to anything but itself and any, however anything is assignable to unknown according to typescript. [Typescript reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware. That's precisely why I expected assigning `b = a` would be forbidden.

Comment: I believe It's because `prop` is optional, so `a` doesn't need to have it. From typescript's perspective it doesn't have it since you defined `a` as `Record<string,unknown>` which is valid for `ObjWithPropFalsy` since it's indexer has `any` value types ,which `unknown` can be assigned to.

Comment: Makes a bit of sense, but the assignment still works if I remove the `[key: string]: any;` part. It stops working only if I swap `prop?: false` with `prop: false | undefined`. Looks like Typescript only cares if the property is there, not if it's assignable, which is really weird to me. I expected `Record<string, any>` to be assignable, but not `Record<string, unknown`.

Comment: It doesn't care about `{ prop: true }`, you can remove it from `a` and it still works. As far as why that still works when you get rid of the indexer on `ObjWithProp`, I'm not sure I'd be guessing. But if I had to guess `{}` is both a valid `ObjWithProp` and `Record<string,unknown>` so maybe that intersection is enough but honestly I don't know. It still works if you specify Record<string,string> so perhaps indexers are special that way.

Comment: Also, when I change the definition of `ObjWithPropTruthy` to `prop:true` in the playground link I still get two numbers when I run it so not sure how you got a string for `f(c)`

Comment: I'm talking about the type information. Type inference shows it's typed as string. I want it to be correctly typed. It's going to print the number `0` either way.

Comment: It is correctly typed, you explicitly defined it as a `ObjWithPropFalsy` which returns a string, so that's what it thinks it's getting. Information about what `prop` is from typescripts perspective is gone once you made `a:Record<string,unknown>`. If someone mis-casts an object typescript will no longer accurately reflect the actual object which is what is happening in your case. Now weather you think the casting sequence you went through should not be valid is a separate question, but based on typescripts implementation it is.

Comment: Variable `c`  is not `ObjWithPropFalsy`, it's `Record`. There are no mis-casts, because I'm not doing any type casting. There are only implicit type casts from the compiler. I'm only doing declarations and assignments.

Comment: 'const a: Record<string, unknown>', is explicit. The only reason the object literal  can be set to ObjWithPropFalsy is because of that explicit definition. As far as `c` goes unless you do `const c = { prop: true } as const;` typescript will just see it as a type with prop:boolean, not the actual value that is set since the value is not a type. If you use `const c = { prop: true } as const;` you'll get the correct typing of `f `since it'll interpret the value of prop as a type. If you use `const c = { prop: true }`, it'll just infer prop:boolean and pick the more generic function overload.

Comment: AFAIK `const a : Record = ...` is not a type cast, but that's beside the point. But yes, `as const` solves the problem. The original question is: how to declare those function overloads to not require the use of `as const`.

Comment: You're right technically it is not a cast, my apologies. I have nothing else to offer, I tried sorry I couldn't help with your problem.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the hard work. Typescript terminology is no joke, someone might nitpick that casts are really called type assertions... I've been struggling with those overload declarations for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does Typescript allow the assignment of Record<string, unknown> into the type ObjWithPropFalsy if I can't assign unknown into false | undefined?

It looks like Typescript is pretty relaxed on assignments of index signatures (like `Record` is). **So if an interface consists of only optionals, Typescript considers any index signature is a match**. This is pretty dangerous, but it simply is as it is (as of TS 4.0.2). [Index Signatures are full of quirks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) that reflect the weirdness of every object being a mapping type in JavaScript.

> How can I achieve the intended return type inference in the overload example above?

Having the first overload be something that `Record` will match, but not the more specific types. Using `never` is one way to do it:

```js
function f(arg: { prop?: never }): number | string;
function f(arg: ObjWithPropTruthy): number;
function f(arg: ObjWithPropFalsy): string;
function f(arg: ObjWithProp): number | string;
function f(arg: ObjWithProp): number | string {
    if (arg.prop) return 0;
    else return "0"
}
```

This way, when passing `any` or `Record<string, unknown>` as argument, the first overload will match. When passing narrower types like `ObjWithPropTruthy`, the first overload won't match because of the `never`.